# Get sha of the last commit before pull

Tags: git, bash

After pull, git lists the files modified since the last pull.

The question is, how to get this list after some more work was done on local repo.

e.g.

```
$ git checkout feature/default2
$ git pull
Updating 5420c70..b8eec49
Fast-forward
 application/configs/application.ini                                 |   1 +
 application/modules/product/forms/Search.php                        |   3 ++
 public/themes/default/bootstrap/buttons.less                        |  25 -----------
 public/themes/default/css/cmspanel.css                              | 234 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------------------------------------
 public/themes/default/css/products.css                              |  57 ++++++++++++++++++++----
 public/themes/default/css/style.css                                 | 270 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-------------------------------------------------
 public/themes/default/gfx/icons/menu-drop-dark.png                  | Bin 0 -> 160 bytes
 public/themes/default/gfx/icons/more.png                            | Bin 0 -> 120 bytes
 public/themes/default/layouts/scripts/footer.phtml                  |  26 ++++++++++-
 public/themes/default/layouts/scripts/gallery.phtml                 |   2 +
 public/themes/default/layouts/scripts/home.phtml                    |   2 +
 public/themes/default/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml                  |   2 +
 public/themes/default/layouts/scripts/products.phtml                |  22 ++++-----
 public/themes/default/less/cmspanel.less                            |  26 +++++++++++
 public/themes/default/less/nav.less                                 |   4 +-
 public/themes/default/less/products.less                            |  61 +++++++++++++++++++++----
 public/themes/default/less/style.less                               |  59 ++++++++++++++++++++++---
 public/themes/default/less/widgets.less                             |  37 +++++++++++++++-
 public/themes/default/modules/cms/scripts/widgets/random.phtml      |   6 +--
 public/themes/default/modules/default/scripts/widgets/submenu.phtml |   2 +-
 public/themes/default/modules/product/scripts/index/view.phtml      |  44 +++++++++---------
 public/themes/default/modules/product/scripts/widgets/search.phtml  |  16 +++++++
 22 files changed, 584 insertions(+), 315 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 public/themes/default/gfx/icons/menu-drop-dark.png
 create mode 100644 public/themes/default/gfx/icons/more.png
```

The `5420c70` is the state before pull.
How to determine that `5420c70` sha?

If I'm correct, the ORIG_HEAD is the state before the last pull (any pull, not the pull which introduced some changes).

Im looking for some magic alias like `git checkout SOME_HEAD` to do `git checkout 5420c70` for me.

I'm trying to setup a `git review` alias, which should diff all the files modified since the last pull, which was not up-to-date.

In a basic case, something like this works:

```
git pull
# lists some chanes file
git diff --name-status ORIG_HEAD..
# diffs them
```

but I'm looking for something like this:

```
git pull
# lists some chanes file
git pull
# up-to-date, no changes
git diff --name-status ORIG_HEAD..
# diffs the files since the last pull which was not up-to-date
```

Comment: are these changes local ? or have they been staged at any point ?

Comment: @user1281385 no, I want to diff changes introduced in the remote repo, by some other developers.

Comment: so see the lines changed before the pull to the current head ?

Comment: @user1281385 yes, but the last pull which was not up-to-date.

Comment: What would you want to do if the second pull also gets some changes? In a very busy repo someone would have pushed between the two pulls. Like a one commenter says below use git reflog.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could check reflog, i.e. `HEAD@{1}`, e.g. it `diff --name-only ..HEAD@{1}`.

As another option, you could do `git fetch` then do `git log -p ..@{upstream}` to see upcoming changes, and then `git merge FETCH_HEAD` to bring the changes into your working copy.

Answer (score 3):

After looking in the reflog, I've found that this is what I was looking for:

```
git reflog --oneline | grep -m 1 "pull " | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

This will return just one sha of the previous successfull pull, which may be used in `show`, `log`, `diff` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want, `git pull` isnt the command you need, You should look at `git fetch`

when that has completed you can do

`git diff HEAD...origin`  note you need 3 dots instead of the usual 2

That will give  a single diff of all changes. When your happy you can merge them in the usual way with `git merge` or by using `git cherry-pick` to select only certain ones

Comment: Yes, with fetch this is easy, but I usually do pull, then I need the diff sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.